# what is the path of the image?

Tags: wordpress

I install wordpress in my pc.
the path of thr theme are **C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\www\www1\wordpress\Building_Child_Themes\wp-content\themes\BLANK-Theme\home.php**

inside the folder   **BLANK-Theme** there are folder cald **images** like **wordpress\Building_Child_Themes\wp-content\themes\BLANK-Theme\images**

inside the file `home.php` I have line `<img src="/images/prod-sprunkler.png" alt="Image of Super Sprocket 1000" />`

I can not sucsses to view the mage when the `home.php` are upload, in the adress bar I see **http://127.0.0.1/www/www1/wordpress/Building_Child_Themes/**

what I miss here ?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use full path. You can take help of default functions to get the full path.

If the style.css file of your wordpress site is in the same directory, you can use the following.

```
<img src="<?php get_stylesheet_directory() ?>/images/prod-sprunkler.png" alt="Image of Super Sprocket 1000" />
```